# cannot convert double into float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is where the error is.

`Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y + 1.29, transform.position.z);`

In target.position.y + 1.29

it's the + 1.29

If it's just int it is ok but I want to be precise.

```
public Transform target;
public float smoothTime = 0.2f;
private Vector3 _velocity = Vector3.zero;

void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(
        target.position.x, target.position.y + 1.29
        , transform.position.z);
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
        targetPosition, ref _velocity, smoothTime);
}
```

}

Comment: `1.29` is a `double` ... `1.29f` would be a `float` ... I'd count this in the category **typo** ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following code below should work.

```
Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y + (float)1.29, transform.position.z);
```

You can convert a `double` to `float` using `(float)`.

Explanation:

You are getting the error because `1.29`, by itself, is a `double`. When creating a new `Vector3`, you need 3 `float`s.

Comment: Key here is that a `float + double` is a `double`, but `float + float` is a `float`, and there is no implicit conversion from `double` to `float`.

Comment: or even better you could just `1.29f`

Answer (score 1):

The following statement should work just fine, with the `f` after the floating-point number.

```
Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(
    target.position.x, target.position.y + 1.29f
    ,transform.position.z);
```

**Now, why do we need to specifically have to denote `f` for floating-point and not for another data type, when in other languages it's default?**

So, the answer is that in `C#` any floating-point number without any notation is considered as `double` by default. and in Unity, most of the Mathematics is being calculated in `float` my reasoning for this is that `float` has less accuracy in floating-point calculation compare to `double`, and due to this less accuracy the processing power needed to calculate is less the doubles so I guess due to this Unity might have chosen `float` instead of `double`, but this is just my speculation/reasoning using my current knowledge.

**TL;DR**

We should use `f` notation to denote floating-point numbers when dealing with Unity's Mathematics, ie. Vectors, Regidbodies, Quaternions, etc. Otherwise, C# and unity will both consider this as double and will throw an error type miss-match.

Comment: It's mainly about the precision .. Unity units usually refer to 1 meter and they use a approximated precision of 0.00001 so there is simply no need for any higher precision for most things in Unity .. so yeah float has better performance and needs less memory space ;)